# Proguard fails with firebase-messaging:17.3.4

Tags: firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Today, my Android build failed in the ProGuard optimization phase with a weird java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error message.

Since my last successful build I hardly changed a thing. I tracked the problem to the version of the com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging api. Version 17.3.3 still works fine, version 17.3.4 is problematic.

I don't know if it is related, but note that the api com.google.firebase:firebase-core is not part of my project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems fixed when using grade plugin 3.3 or later